# eventUpdate function updates all the events in the calendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm really going crazy about this one. I have external events that needs to be dropped on the calendar. Whenever I try to drop a new event on the calendar with existing events on it, all of the events update according to the data of the newly dropped event. On the database, after adding the first new event, the second new event duplicates and inserts the number of existing events in the database but with different dates, but same titles and etc. Also, I'm using a modal to pick various data and insert them into the database.

Below is my code for the js:

```
$("#save-assign").click(function() {
    var batch;
    var course = $("#course").val();
    var year = $("#year").val();
    var index = $("#year").prop("selectedIndex");
    if (index > 4) {
        batch = course + '-' + year.substr(6,7);
    }
    else {
        batch = course + '-0' + year.charAt(0);
    }

    $("#course-hidden").val(course);
    $("#yrlvl-hidden").val(year);
    var title = "<h5>Class Schedule for " + batch + "</h5>";

    $.ajax({
        url: eventurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: { action: "check", batch: batch },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(batch);
            if (data.check == "true") {
                alert("This section already exists.");
                $("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.check);
                $("#title").html(title).fadeIn().show();
                $("#external-events").fadeIn().show();
                $("#assign").hide().fadeOut();
                $("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);

                $("#add-sched").fullCalendar({
                    defaultDate: moment("2016-12-11"),
                    utc: true,
                    header: false,
                    columnFormat: 'dddd',
                    allDaySlot: false,
                    hiddenDays: [0],
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    minTime: '07:00:00',
                    maxTime: '21:00:00',
                    editable: true,
                    droppable: true,
                    lazyFetching: true,
                    eventOverlap: false,
    //                events: {
    //                    editable: true
    //                },
    //                    select: function(start, end) {
    //                        start = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS+08:00");
    //                        end = start.add(1, "h");
    //                    },
                    drop: function(event, ui) {
                        classname = $(this).attr("id");
                    },
                    eventRender: function(event, element) { 
                        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/><div class='desc'>" + event.description + "</div>"); 
                        event.className = classname;
                    },
                    eventReceive: function(event) {
                        $("#new-subj").modal("show");

                        $("#save-subj").click(function() {
                            var subjcode = $("#subjcode").val();
                            var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS");
                            var end = moment(start).add(1, "h").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
                            var prof = $("#prof").val();
                            var profname = $("#prof option:selected").text();
                            var room = $("#room").val();
                            var roomname = "Rm. " + $("#room option:selected").text();
                            var course = $("#course-hidden").val();
                            var yrlvl = $("#yrlvl-hidden").val();

                            console.log(event.id);
                            event.title = subjcode;
                            event.start = start;
                            event.end = end;
                            event.description = profname + "<br/>" + roomname;
                            event.className = classname;

                            $.ajax({
                                url: eventurl,
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {
                                    batch: batch,
                                    subjcode: subjcode,
                                    prof: prof,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    room: room,
                                    course: course,
                                    yrlvl: yrlvl,
                                    classname: classname,
                                    action: "add"
                                },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(data) {
                                    event.id = data.eventid;
                                    console.log(data.eventid);
                                    $("#add-sched").fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

                                    $("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
                                },
                                error: function(e){
                                    console.log("adding event: "+e.responseText);
                                }
                            });

                            $("#add-sched").fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

                            $("#new-subj").modal("hide");

                            $("#subjcode").val("");
                            $("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
                        });

                        $("#cancel-subj").click(function() {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                            getEvents();
                        });
                    },
                    eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                        if (isElemOverDiv(jsEvent)) {
                            swal({
                                title: "Are you sure you want to delete this subject?",
                                type: "warning",
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                confirmButtonColor: "",
                                confirmButtonText: "Delete",
                                closeOnConfirm: false
                            },
                            function(isConfirm) {
                                if (isConfirm) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: eventurl,
                                        type: "POST",
                                        data: {
                                            id: event.id,
                                            action: "delete"
                                        },
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function(data) {
                                            console.log(data);
                                            if (data.status == "success") {
                                                console.log(event.id);
                                                setTimeout(function(){
                                                    calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                                                    getEvents();
                                                    swal("Deleted", "The subject has been deleted.", "success");
                                                }, 2000);
                                            }
                                        },
                                        error: function(e){ 
                                            console.log('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    });

    $("#assign-batch").modal("hide");
});
```

**schedules.php**

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db-config.php");

$action = $_POST['action'];

if ($action == "add") {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO schedules(batchid, subjectcode, prof_id, start, end, room, course, yearlevel, classname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $batch, $subjcode, $prof, $start, $end, $rm, $course, $yrlvl, $classname);
    $batch = $_POST['batch'];
    $subjcode = $_POST['subjcode'];
    $prof = $_POST['prof'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];
    $rm = $_POST['room'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $yrlvl = $_POST['yrlvl'];
    $classname = $_POST['classname'];
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $lastid = $conn->insert_id;
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','eventid'=>$lastid));
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

My console logs while adding new events showing their `event.id`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the eventReceive event runs, you add another "click" event to the "save-subj" element - the "click" code you've defined runs again. But it just adds another handler, and another, and another, each time. The previous event handlers don't get removed. They continue to exist, and understand "event" (since it's inherited from the wrapping function) to be "event" as it existed when the handler was declared.

Therefore every time you drag a new event on, all the previous handlers run (as you've noticed by your logging), referencing each of the previously dragged events in turn, and these events are given a new title and description using the current value from the HTML controls in your modal - since you request these afresh each time.

The solution is to move the whole `$("#save-subj").click(function() {` block outside the "eventReceive" function, to a place where you're sure it will only be executed once (therefore you only get one instance of the handler). This leaves you with a problem of how you pass the "event" variable to it, since it's no longer within scope. I suggest that within the eventReceive function you save the id of the "event" somewhere suitable just before you open the modal - either in a "data-" attribute of an element in the modal, or maybe in a new JS variable that is in scope for both the eventReceive function and the click handler. Then in the click handler, modify it so it retrieves that event ID, then fetches the event data from the calendar in order to manipulate it.

If any of that isn't clear I might be able to put together a short code example.